# Resource annotation in servlets triggers squid:S2226

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

When I try to use the Resource annotation in a servlet, Sonar triggers rule squid:S2226 "Servlets should not have mutable instance fields" and tells me make the variable final or static.

But resource injection does not work and final and static variables.

Is it a bug in sonar or resource injection is not recommended anymore in servlets ?

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/database")
    private DataSource dataSource;
}
```

A similar conundrum appears with ServletConfig

```
private ServletConfig config;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.config = config;
}
```

Here, `config` cannot be made final, but making it static trigger the other rule squid:S2696 : "Instance methods should not write to "static" fields"

I meet this situation with SonarLint for Eclipse 3.3.1.201712071600, if that is useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Injected Members**

You are right about injected Members (@EJB, @Resource, ...) and there are (now fixed) [Issues](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2744?jql=text%20~%20%22S2226%22) in the SONARJAVA Issue Tracker.

For example [SONARJAVA-2744](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2744?jql=text%20~%20%22S2226%22)
Title: "S2226 should not raise issues for field annotated with @Resource"
Solved with Version 5.4 of the Security Rules

**Members initialized in #init**

There is another (solved) issue: [SONARJAVA-1458](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1458)
Members initialized in #init should not trigger squid:S2226.

According *ServletConfig*:
Usually there is no need to hold a reference to *ServletConfig* because it is accessible using *GenericServlet#getServletConfig*.